# How to import a .sql file to the android room database?

Tags: android, sql, android-room

Does anyone know how to import a downloaded sql file to the android database via room?
I have a .sql file in android phone which is exported from mysql database. I want to import the .sql file to the android sql database.
I try to use the room of android JetPack. I check the official site:https://developer.android.google.cn/training/data-storage/room/creating-views
But dont find a way to do that.

The content in my .sql file is like:

```
DELETE FROM NewsInfo WHERE id = '20210524210624';
INSERT INTO NewsInfo VALUES ('20210524210624','2','aaa','bbb',3,'','','','en','push','2021-05-24 21:06:24');
```

So does anyone know how to import a downloaded sql file to the room on Android?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I know of is to retrieve the actual db object from Room that has the execSQL() function.
And stream in the .sql file for each line `db.execSQL(line);`
(edit) If I knew this information wasn't readily available I would have posted the example, but I actually couldn't find it myself.

```
RoomDatabase database = ...
SupportSQLiteDatabase db = database.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();

db.beginTransaction();
db.execSQL(line);
db.endTransaction();
```

Comment: How to retrieve the actual db object from Room? The class RoomDatabase seems not have function execSQL()

Comment: Seems dont need  db.beginTransaction(); and db.endTransaction(); with which wont  be work.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply call the query method on your Database instance.

```
appDatabase.query("YOUR INSERT QUERY")
```

So call the above method for each query you get in the .sql file.

Comment: didn't work for me